HoloLens 2 Development with Unity
I'm going to develop an app for HoloLens 2 with Vuforia Engine. I've googled that the minimum supported Unity version of Vuforia is Unity 2022. Still, I've also found that some people said it has only to be Unity 2020 version to develop a HoloLens 2 app. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?
Can I use Unity 2022 version to develop a HoloLens 2 app?
Now my current version is:
Unity 2020.3.44f1
Vuforia 10-22-5
And it started to show some problems to me such as not generate the preview of model target and image target.

Hi, I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be Unity 2020. This page: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/supported-versions lists what's needed to develop with Vuforia on Windows platforms. It states 2022.3.16f1+ and newer as the recommended versions.

@thesbyro Yes. The recommended version of developing Vuforia is Unity 2022, but some of the developers said that it has to be Unity 2020 to develop a HoloLens 2 app. Here’s where the problem is.

I would check when these statements were made. It was probably true once, but today, it should be Unity LTS 2022 or newer when using Vuforia. Maybe the developers use other plugins that require an older version.

You can certainly use Unity 2022 to develop HoloLens 2 apps. And actually Unity 2022.3 LTS is the recommended version for HoloLens 2 development at the moment. See Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin.

We recommend that you use the latest patch version of 2022.3 LTS and their recommended version of Unity plugins, together with
the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin.
If using an earlier Unity patch release, be sure to consult the known blocking issues table to ensure that you avoid builds with other blocking issues.

